# iOS Location for Apps Less Specific than Android Apps

Tags: android, ios, swift, locationmanager, cllocation

This may be a simple thing.

I have an app I developed in Android wherein I get the location and ultimately the latitude and longitude, which get returned to me in the code with coordinates that look like this for example:
latitude = 37.7858347 ; longitude = -122.4064172;

But in iOS, I use the LocationManager location and when accessing latitude and longitude, they look like this:
latitude = 37.785834 ; longitude = -122.406417;

So you can see the issue where it is one digit short or less precise, which may not sound like a lot but makes my app much more useless in iOS.

Does anyone know how to get it to be as accurate as Android? I have tried researching this a fair amount and have set the desiredAccuracy to `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` along with some other choice but does not seem to change anything.

Below are the 2 relevant code excerpts from iOS and a pic to see what I have set things to in info.plist. If it matters any my background is a very experienced Java developer but new to Swift and iOS.
Thanks.

```
if let currentLocation = locationManager?.location {
    var longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    var latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    
    print("latitude = \(latitude) ; longitude = \(longitude);");
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    var gsTask: GSearchAddressTask?
    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!
    let progressBar = ProgressText(text: "Loading")
    let progressText: UITextView = UITextView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webview = WKWebView()
        //webview.navigationDelegate = self
        
        // Get location permission
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

Plist (ignore the blue line):

[image: Info.plist file]

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but are you sure the Android one is more precise? It's a different value, but is it actually correct?

Comment: I really think that the last decimal digit on Android is not precise (should be ignored). Numbers are usually saved in a 32-bit floating point format, whose precision is just 6 decimal places...

Comment: How exact do you expect it to be?  10m of inaccuracy in GPS coordinates is pretty common on cell phone level hardware.

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 in Android the location is a double (64 bit) number.  Of course the only factor in accuracy isn't the floating point precision, there's also the hardware precision.  Which is a far greater source of inaccuracy.

Comment: It's definitely more precise and certainly is when I search based on those coordinates for the business in question (which is what used for). I expect it to be 7 decimal places of precision and am pretty sure this is the standard because if you even just do a regular search on maps.google.com for say the Empire State Building or whatever then it will show the latitude and longitude coordinates in the URL and they are 7 digits decimal precision.
Let me know if you have any other suggestions. I am pretty sure this is just a matter of knowing how to get it more precisely with Swift IOS code.

Comment: It seems I can NOT force it like this:
var latitude = String(format: "%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

As it just shows 4 zeros at the end, so it is still stuck at 6 decimals of precision.